# Assembly language procedure to take 2-digit input from the user

Tags: assembly, input, x86, hex

I have a procedure which takes a 2-digit input from the user but I don't understand  why a jump is made to JUMP01 if AL <= 9 and otherwise 7 is subtracted

```
INPUT PROC NEAR

    MOV AH,01
    INT 21H
    SUB AL,30H
    CMP AL,09
    JBE JUMP01
    SUB AL,07H
JUMP01:

    MOV DL,AL
    SHL DX,4
    MOV AH,01
    INT 21H
    SUB AL,30H
    CMP AL,09
    JBE JUMP02
    SUB AL,07H
JUMP02: 

    ADD DL,AL
    RET

INPUT ENDP
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is reading a 2 digit number in **hexadecimal**. The reason for the subtraction is that the letters `A` through `F` should be mapped to the range `10` through `15` (decimal). The ascii code of `A` is 65 which is reduced by `48` (the `sub al, 30h`) leaving 17, and to get to `10` from there it has to be reduced by a further `7`. This works for the other letters too.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to worry, this code just reads hex,assumes capital Letters and does not check about any other chars typed.

It first subtracts '0', so in case of a digit you will have a result le 9.

If not, it assumes you typed 'A'..'F', (0x41..0x46),and therefore subtracts 7 to get the correct result 0x0a..0x0f